# Why the decimal marker I get is not the one defined in NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS?

Tags: oracle, number-formatting, localization

According to the Oracle documentation, [`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e24448/initparams151.htm) stores the decimal marker used by the current session. To get the current `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`, I use this request:

```
select value
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
```

And I get this result:

```
VALUE
,
```

So my decimal marker is 'comma'.

But when I make a SELECT request to get a decimal value, the decimal marker return by Oracle is different. If I run this dummy request:

```
select 3/2 decimal_value from dual;
```

I get this result:

```
DECIMAL_VALUE
1.5
```

So, my questions are: why is it not `1,5` as expected? What need I change to get the decimal marker as defined is `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`?

**Important note:** I can't change my SELECT request.

---

After reading [this article](http://edstevensdba.com/oracle-data-types/understanding-oracle-date-formats/) (suggested by @EdStevens in the comments), here are some precisions.

According to the article, the decimal marker is defined by :

1. The NLS values defined in the database initialization parameters
2. The NLS settings of the OS of the client
3. The NLS settings of the Oracle client
4. The parameters of the `TO_CHAR` function if it is used in the SELECT statement

In our case, because we don't use `TO_CHAR` function in the SELECT statement, the decimal marker should be defined by the NLS settings of the Oracle client (`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`) but we saw above that is not the case.

Interresting fact, if I use `TO_CHAR` function in my SELECT statement:

```
select TO_CHAR(3/2) decimal_value from dual;
```

I get this result:

```
DECIMAL_VALUE
1,5
```

If `nlsparam` is omitted, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) says:

> If you omit `nlsparam` or any one of the parameters, then this
>   function uses the default parameter values for your session.

So, when we use `TO_CHAR` function, Toad use the NLS value of the session but not in the others cases.

Is it possible that Toad performs an implicit conversion (NUMBER -> CHAR) before printing the value in the data grid without using NLS parameters? If it is the case, why this implicit conversion don't use `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`? What can I do to get my number in the correct format?

---

Here is a little recap of the informations present in the comments:

- The problem I expose above is made with Toad for Oracle (version
  9.1.0.62) but I also reproduce this issue on the application I develop who uses OCI drivers.
- The session value of `NLS_TERRITORY` is France, `NLS_LANGUAGE` is French and `NLS_LANG` is `FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252`. Those values are defined in the Windows registry.
- If I use `SQL*Plus`, I get a correct result. Indeed the decimal marker corresponds to the one defined in `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` and if I change this value, it directly changed the decimal marker I get (that is not the case with Toad).

Comment: What is the value of `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` ?  I cannot replicate your results with Oracle 12c.

Comment: @MarkStewart `NLS_LANGUAGE` is FRENCH and `NLS_TERRITORY` is FRANCE.

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: @MichaelKutz I'm using Toad for Oracle (version 9.1.0.62) but I also noticed this problem on the application I develop who uses OCI drivers.

Comment: @Pierre - It is the application's responsibility to translate the data `Typ=2 Len=3: 193,2,51` into strings `1.5` or `1,5`, not the RDBMS.  Check with `SQL*Plus` and/or `SQL*Developer`.

Comment: When I use SQL*Plus on the same server as the database, Oracle 12c, setting `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` as you have, I get `1,5` so I agree with @Michael that this is a client issue.  Check the environment variables on the client you are using.

Comment: @MichaelKutz On `SQL*Plus`, I get `1,5`. But what should I understand by "It is the application's responsibility to translate the data"? Does it mean Toad for Oracle does a bad job? And, in the application I develop, must I take care of the translation from `.` (default Oracle separator) to the decimal marker defined in `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`?

Comment: @MarkStewart When you said "this is a client issue", you mean it's a problem of Toad or it's a problem of my system config? As I said before, on `SQL*Plus`, I get correct results (even when I change `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`). Also, I have this problem on other machines. Which environment variables can be responsible of this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure it is important in my case: I also precise that my Windows regional settings are configured in "Français (France)" like my Oracle `NLS_LANG`.

Comment: If your `SQL*Plus` client and `Toad` client are both on the same windows machine, could be that `SQL*Plus` is using an environment variable and Toad is not; open a command prompt (AKA DOS prompt) window, and invoke a `set` command, and see if any variables containing `LANG` or `NLS` show up.  Also fire up `regedit.exe`  and search starting at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` to see if `NLS_LANG` is set.  I doubt Toad looks there.

Comment: @MarkStewart I have no `LANG` nor `NLS` environment variable set on my system. But, indeed, I have a registry value `NLS_LANG` sets to `FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252`.

Comment: @MarkStewart I tested to change the value of `NLS_LANG` in the registry and it has an impact on the results I got from Toad and also from my application who uses OCI.

Comment: Great; as long as it had the correct impact, and SQL*Plus still works, say what you did where as the answer to this question!

Comment: You need to be aware that the NLS settings at the database level are just a starting point.  They are easily over-ridden at various other levels, mostly at the client.  These can include OS enviornment variables (or registry settings, in the case of Windblows), database session settings as set by the client, or explicit settings used by the client code, such as use of to_char() functions. I wrote an article (http://edstevensdba.com/oracle-data-types/understanding-oracle-date-formats/) that explains this as regards DATE data, but the same principles apply to numbers.

Comment: @MarkStewart When I said it has an impact, I want to say that when I change the value of `NLS_LANG` in the registry, it changes the behavior of Toad. Conclusion: Toad reads the `NLS_LANG` value. But I still don't have the behavior I want: get a comma as decimal marker (whatever the value of `NLS_LANG`, I still got a point as decimal separator).

Comment: @EdStevens I read your article and I add some precisions in my post. Indeed, if I use `TO_CHAR`, it works well but without this function, the NLS value of my Oracle session are not taken into account.

Comment: @Pierre, don't forget that the _session_setting can be overridden by the client app code.  Without the to_char() to convert the data from a number or date into a varchar2, then the app itself still gets a number or date and is free to do with as it will.  And all the generalized GUI clients, like SQL Developer, have their own settings to control this.

Comment: @EdStevens I saw, in Toad for Oracle, the option to change a date format if `TO_CHAR` is not used. But nothing like that for a `NUMBER`. Do you mean Toad arbitrarily choose to format floating number with a point as decimal marker if `TO_CHAR` is not used?

Comment: @Pierre, I have no experience with Toad, but I'd be shocked if it did no provide a method of controlling that.  Perhaps someone at the Toad forum would know. See https://community.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10